# Chain Jquery doesn't work with select box

Tags: jquery

i have a code that doesn't work.
It's a chain script which works with this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
</select>
<script src="//www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/jquery.chained.min.js" charset=utf-8></script> <script charset=utf-8>
  $(function(){
      $("#series").chained("#mark");
  });
</script>
```

But if i try to write this:

```
include "Test.php"
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="zero"> </option>
  <?php 
  /*foreach($col->query("SELECT DISTINCT `naz` FROM `origine`") as $naz)
  {
    echo "<option value=".$naz['naz'].">".$naz['naz']."</option>";
  }*/
  foreach($lista as $elementi)
  {
    echo "<option  value='".$elementi."'>".$elementi."</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="zero" class="zero">--</option>
<?php 
foreach($cittadina as $numero)
{
    foreach($numero as $paese=>$p)
    {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $p?>" class="<?php echo "ciao"?>"><?php echo $p?></option>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
</select>
<script src="//www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/jquery.chained.min.js" charset=utf-8></script> <script charset=utf-8>
  $(function(){
      $("#series").chained("#mark");
  });
</script>
```

it shows all elements without first selection...where is my fault?
If i try the original script all work, i can see available only the first select box and after i change it, the second select box is available. Originally i written this code with SQL Language but it didn't work.

Ty so much

Comment: Why are you adding the plugin twice (local copy and remote)?

Comment: i made a mistake,, the real line is: <option value="<?php echo $p?>" class="<?php echo $paese?>"><?php echo $p?></option> i changed for a test

Comment: the script chained/jquery.chained.min.js? my fault, i didn't see it

Comment: i traied to create arrays in this way:
if($nazioni=='AE'){?><option value="<?php echo $citta?>" class=AE><?php echo $citta?></option><?php } 
 if($nazioni=='AF'){?><option value="<?php echo $citta?>" class=AF><?php echo $citta?></option><?php } 
 if($nazioni=='AG'){?><option value="<?php echo $citta?>" class=AG><?php echo $citta?></option><?php } 

with less than 10 select it works, over this 10 elements when i open the php page it load all elements at the same time and it is very slow, why?